# Why is the % symbol not showing with XeTeX?

Tags: symbols, xetex

I'm using XeTeX and my % symbol is not showing when I compile to PDF! I've added my code below. I've gone through the XeTeX companion guide (maybe not very thoroughly) and Googled, but I can't find out why this is happening. I would totally appreciate anyone telling me why it's not working and how to fix it.

```
\begin{description} \fontspec[]{ArchitectsDaughter} As 1\% RF = 1 cM, two genes which lie 100 cM apart should have a recombination frequency of 100 \% \end{description}
```

Thanks in advance!

BTW, I'm using XeTeX and LaTeX at the same time... if this bit of information is helpful...

---

EDIT:

Apparently my font doesn't have a `%` glyph... and now I feel like a total dork for not coming to that conclusion sooner.

---

Comment: Please post a full minimal example (starting `\documentclass` and ending `\end{document}`)

Comment: Okay, I've added that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This minimal example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\begin{document}
\fontspec[]{Minion Pro} As 1\% RF = 1 cM, two genes which lie 100 cM apart should have a recombination frequency of 100\%
\end{document}
```

gives the expected output. I am guessing that your Architects Daughter font does not have a `%` glyph. Check it's [character map at Font Squirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/architects-daughter).

Comment: You are very right... I should have checked that first! Thanks for help!